# Playing a game, a Chinese player says this: "德莱厄斯两兄弟" What does it mean?

Tags: translation

I was getting along with a teammate, and then a third guy (who was speaking english before) says this:

德莱厄斯两兄弟

Google translate just says "Two Brothers",
and I can't figure a different definition by looking at each character individually

Is this an actual phrase?  Or perhaps an English speaker plugging something into google translate and getting random gibberish?

Comment: According to the comment by @TooskyHierot you might be seeing this in League of Legends. You should provide that information to indicate the context, if this is the case.

Comment: Could he be insulting you as 'dumb ass brothers'?

Comment: This refers to two person both have the last name 德莱厄斯 who are brothers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are playing LOL, and then 德莱厄斯 is Darius ( the Hand of Noxus). So, “德莱厄斯两兄弟” means “Darius and his brother (Draven (the Glorious Executioner))”. So maybe your team or the other team summoned both Darius and Draven, and that bro commented on this. Have fun~

Comment: haha that is exactly it!  our team had both darius and draven.  There was no other context in the conversation so I had no idea what was happening.  that's actually hilarious, and explains why I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

德莱厄斯两兄弟 is *two brothers of 德莱厄斯*, that is, *you two share the same surname 德莱厄斯 and you two are bros*.

Sometimes, this type of addressing implies that these two persons are prominent in the certain area. E.g. in tennis, we address *Venus Williams* and *Serena Williams* as 威廉姆斯姐妹.

Comment: 并非如此 德莱厄斯（诺克萨斯之手）和德莱文（荣耀行刑官）是英雄联盟LOL游戏中的两名英雄，在设定上是兄弟。我猜这名中国玩家在外服上看到了己方或对方选出了这两位英雄才吐槽一句的吧。

Comment: @TooskyHierot, 你可能是对的。但这种说法是不准确的。 一般来讲，德莱厄斯两兄弟指的是两个人都叫德莱厄斯。 如果一个叫德莱厄斯， 另一个叫德莱文， 那应该称作： 德莱厄斯和德莱文两兄弟。我的回答是针对一般语言环境而言的。

Comment: 你说的有道理，然而应当可以推断出是这个意思（从游戏以及德莱厄斯这个名字）ԅ(¯ㅂ¯ԅ)